# Conceptual question on interpreting magnitude graphs

Tags: filter, schematics, bode-plot

I am designing a band pass filter and I am having trouble understanding how to interpret my simulation results.
[image]

What I think this is telling me is that when I send a frequency through one of my filters, the magnitude of the output signal is proportional to the dB gain. So on my low pass filter, I get out slightly less than the same signal I put in, and it decreases down to its cutoff at about 200 Hz. Assuming what I stated is correct, then the band pass filters are activating in the right regions, but hardly activating at all.

So to fix this, would I use an amplifier after the band pass filter to bring the signal back up to match the low and high filters? Secondly, would amplifying the signal before I send it through the filter shift the output up, relative to what it is now? I hope I'm making sense.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you read/studied any textbook about filter theory ? Your using of terms like *"output signal is proportional to the dB gain"* and *"filters are activating in the right regions, but hardly activating at all"* makes me suspect that you haven't. If you do not have a good book at hand, this might be a reasonable starting point: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_4.html

Comment: I would propse to display the results down to (at least) -20 dB. This would give a much clearer picture - in particular for the bandpass. If more output voltage is neede, I would place an amplifier AFTER the filter (no filter loading due to any connected devices). Furthermore, I support FakeMoustache`s comment.

Comment: The statement "magnitude of the output signal is proportional to the dB" is wrong. The label dB means that the ratio of output to input **power** is \$10^{0.1w}\$ where \$w\$ is numerical value labled dB. I.e. the power is not proportional to \$w\$ but to an exponential expression of \$w\$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two notable things to say about the types of filter you have used: -

- Passive filters don't need a power supply (a good thing) but they are much more difficult to design if you require steep rejection of out-of-band signals
- You have cascaded two first order filters and their interaction will "muddy the water". This is due to loading effects of the 2nd RC on the first RC and the impedance of the 1st RC imposed on the 2nd RC.

If you want steep bandpass filters like this: -

[image]

Then it is likely you will need to use two 2nd order active circuits. I say this because the type of filter above has well-defined upper and lower 3dB breakpoints and a flat central area and this type of characteristic fits the bill for an active design.

However, if you want a characteristic like this: -

[image]

You can achieve it with an LCR circuit as shown. Note that there are two examples - one has a sharper peak than the other and this is due to the ratio of L to C.

Comment: Wow thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I will investigate some active filter designs though, if you say that would work better. Also, what formulas did you use to pick those values?